# Перестал компилироваться проект maven

Tags: java, maven

Долгое время все отлично компилировалось и собиралось, в один момент стали собираться только модули. Сборка проходит нормально, насколько я понимаю, но так как классы не компилируются полученый jar содержит только файлы библиотек. В чем может быть дело?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Znatoki</groupId>
    <artifactId>StudyRussian</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.5</version>
    <modules>
        <module>WordManager</module>
        <module>SettingManager</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intellij/forms_rt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>StudyRussian/StudyRussian</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Set a compiler level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ru.AlexeyFedechkin.znatoki.StudyRussian.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-data</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>data</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>rule.json</include>
                                        <include>word.json</include>
                                        <include>wrongMessages.json</include>
                                        <include>setting.json</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/StudyRussian/data</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-WordManager</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>WordManager/target/</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>WordManager-jar-with-dependencies.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/StudyRussian</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-SettingManager</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>SettingManager/target/</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>SettingManager-jar-with-dependencies.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/StudyRussian</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: а какую команду вы запускаете в мавене?

Comment: если речь о том, что собираются jar'ы только у двух модулей, а в родительский jar нет, то так и должно быть - родительский pom это описательный пом для всего проекта и он не порождает артефактов, только их описание